# How can you lock a luggage's wheels to stop them from moving?

Tags: travel

My luggage lacks any method to lock the wheels (I will try to buy one next time with this feature), and so that rolls on buses and trains without luggage holders; it resembles the following:

[image]

I must not position the luggage on its side, which would dirty or damage it on the floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pink pencil eraser cut into a wedge shape can be jammed between wheel and caster base on two wheels, to act as a brake.  It can be inserted and removed in seconds, and makes no permanent changes to the luggage.  If you find the large size, you can probably make two such wedges from a single eraser for under a dollar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about a hack, it will be better if you could replace two front wheels with this type of wheels.

[image]

For this you could reach out to a repairer. This would help you to avoid inserting pencil eraser frequenlty. I hope you know about the working of these stoppers and would be easy to get started using this stoppers. I am not branding this same product, you could go for similar types.